# Is it possible to have Django actually upload a default file when using Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage, djangae

I'm using Djangae, with Google Cloud Storage as my storage backend. I'd like to know how I can set a default ImageField value and have it actually be processed by the upload mechanism and sent to the cloud. I could manually upload the file myself using a signal if the user didn't provide an image, but it'd be nice to find a simpler solution.

Environment:

Djangae 0.9.11

Django 1.11.20

Python 2.7

Comment: Why would you want to upload the same image multiple times for all your users? Can't you display a static file when the user didn't upload an image? But in any case, you can always assign the image field yourself in code. For example if you generate a unique image somehow you can just assign it and it will be saved as if it were uploaded.

Comment: For a few reasons, but mainly because I need to be able to change the default without modifying images already in the wild.

Comment: Which would be made *harder* by your proposal. As dirk says, use a single already-uploaded default.

Comment: How does my proposal make changing the default without modifying the look and feel of existing widgets harder? In my opinion, managing an out-of-band, "already-uploaded default" is harder and would require making changes in -- at least -- two places (the default path in the app and the external asset itself) if the default needed to be updated.

Comment: Yep as others have said, if no profile pic, show the default...